# $vuetify.breakpoint is empty

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, breakpoints, vuetify.js

On any of the VueJS projects I generate and install Vuetify I can't use `this.$vuetify.breakpoint.ANYTHING` because `this.$vuetify.breakpoint` is empty.

I tried with any versions of Vuetify from 1.0.10 to 1.0.17. I don't understand why. My `main.ts` file look like this:

```
import './hooks' // This must be imported before any component
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'
import 'roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css'
import './styles/global.css'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#0031FF',
    secondary: '#424242'
  }
})

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Where can't you use it? And what does the error say?

Comment: I can't use it in any component. The object is just empty, there is no error

Comment: Did you wrap your app in `v-app` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start):

> In order for your application to work properly, you must wrap it in a
>   `v-app` component. This component is used for dynamically managing your
>   content area and is the mounting point for many components.